# Error convert BigDecimal to int

Tags: java, list, casting

I have the following situation:

```
List<BigDecimal> nvs = servSuperlivelloDAO.findNetworkVersion(year, daynumber);
int[] res = new int[nvs.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < nvs.size(); i++) {
    res[i] = nvs.get(i).intValue();
}
```

transforming BigDecimal to int gives this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal

I don't understand why I have a Integer in BigDecimal list.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Problem is not in the posted code.

Comment: seems that `.findNetworkVersion()` actually returns list of `Integer`, not `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess the problem is in the fist line

```
List<BigDecimal> nvs = servSuperlivelloDAO.findNetworkVersion(year, daynumber);
```

Try debugging the findnetworkVersion() method. And check the return type of that method. (is it really List of BigDecimal?).

Comment: The problem is not so much the inner working of findNetworkVersion (as would be revealed by debugging), not strictly speaking the declared return type of the method. The primary relevant question is the runtime type/s of the objects in the list returned. You may check those with a debugger, with a call to getClass() and/or with instanceof tests in your code.

Comment: As per the question, the error says - java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal. That means, somewhere Integer is being returned and assigned to BigDecimal. It's not "the transforming from BigInteger to Integer", as mentioned in the question (it's the other way round).

Comment: @OleV.V. By debugging i meant to find what that function ( findNetworkVersion() ) is returning.

Comment: Alright, @Akash, I misunderstood what you were aiming at. We agree, really.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it seems that your problem is that `servSuperlivelloDAO.findNetworkVersion()` returns a list that contains at least one object that has type `Integer`, not `BigDecimal`.

**The fix is simple**: declare `nvs` as `List<? extends Number> nvs`:

```
    List<? extends Number> nvs = servSuperlivelloDAO.findNetworkVersion(year, daynumber);
    int[] res = new int[nvs.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < nvs.size(); i++) {
        res[i] = nvs.get(i).intValue();
    }
```

Now the list can contain `Integer` or  `BigDecimal` objects or a mix of both, and your code will work fine. I don’t know whether `findNetworkVersion()` is declared to return `List<BigDecimal>`, but if it is, you can still assign to a variable of type `List<? extends Number>` just like that because `BigDecimal` is a subtype of `Number`. And the rest works because `Integer` too is a subclass of `Number`. And the `intValue` method that you are using is declared in `Number`. So you can call it no matter the concrete type of the object.

**What happened in your code?** You had declared `nvs` to have type `List<BigDecimal>`. The compiler believes you, so when you do `nvs.get(i).intValue()`, it takes an object out of the list and tries to convert it to `BigDecimel` in order to call its `intValue` method. In one instance you got an `Integer` object instead, and conversion failed with the exception that you saw.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the DAO method : **servSuperlivelloDAO.findNetworkVersion(year, daynumber)** returned an int instead of a BigDecimal . Check it !

Here is an example where the BigDecimal was casted to int without any error:

```
package test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<BigDecimal>  list = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
        list.add(new BigDecimal(1));
        list.add(new BigDecimal(2));
        int arr[] =new int[list.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            arr[i] = list.get(i).intValue();
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }

    }
}
```